# LBO feature in this charger IC

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I'm using this [demo board](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51812b.pdf) and this is the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf) of the charger IC.

I'm trying to test the below-LBO state (refer to flowchart on page 21 of DS):

[image]

I'm charging a 4.2 V Li-ion battery. With this 4.2 V Li-ion battery we can't achieve this LBO state, right?

[image]

According to the Electrical Characteristics table (first line item), the supply voltage to the module has to be 300 mV greater than Vreg. If Vreg is 4.2 V, then the minimum input supply voltage is 4.5 V.

However, the maximum battery voltage is 4.2 V.

So, we can never achieve Vin < Vbat to check the LBO status output, right?

Comment: I suspect they may be referring to the case where Vin is not supplied; i.e. the charger is disconnected from the mains. Vin > Vbat is only necessary to charge the battery.  A low battery alarm can be triggered when the battery voltage is low and the charger voltage is not present.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica, thank you for the comment. When there's no input voltage, how would the charge show the indication?

Comment: By drawing power from the battery. I believe this is intended to act similar to a USB power bank, or perhaps inside a pair of wireless headphones or any other battery-powered equipment. The MCP73871 is always connected to the battery, but the external power (Vin) is connected/disconnected by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, we can never achieve Vin < Vbat to check the LBO status output, right?

Of course you can.

If you read the datasheet thoroughly you'd notice that the LBO is an indication of

- that the system is running from the battery,
- and the battery level is low (the threshold is a pre-set voltage around 3V, depending on the part number)

So, if there's no input voltage or if the input voltage is too low that is not enough to supply the system and charge the battery then the system (chip and the load) will be supplied from the battery. You can see this in detail from the block diagram given in the datasheet.

In this case, battery will drain quicker. And once its voltage hits LBO threshold (3V, 3.1V, 3.2V or whatever it is) the LBO indication will be on.

EDIT: Following is an excerpt from [the eval board U/M](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51755a.pdf):

[image: ![enter image description here]

See the red-underlined. Still fits the definition. Also follow the instructions given in the NOTE box to evaluate the LBO function.

Comment: So, for the LBO threshold, the voltage of the battery should be less than the threshold around 3V, right? And then the input voltage should not be given? Or can the input voltage be given and has to be less than battery voltage? As per the flowchart diagram, I think it mentions that the input voltage has to be given and must be less than battery voltage, right?

Comment: @Newbie If the chip has LBO feature then it'll be given in the part number. Three different versions available: 3V, 3.1V, 3.2V. So, depending on the part you are using, the battery voltage should hit this threshold (with a hysteresis of 0.35V IIRC). Input voltage doesn't have to be applied as it's possible to supply the chip and the load from the battery (check the block diagram). Input is constantly monitored, so whether it's applied or not, it must be lower than the battery voltage for LBO.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, my part has the LBO feature available. I verified. So, with or with the input voltage, I can verify the LBO status output, right?

Comment: @Newbie Correct. But the battery voltage should be around the threshold voltage as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have the module with me, let me check and come back

Comment: From what I checked from the Eval board is that, when the input is disconnected and I have connected the battery with no load, none of the STATx LEDs are glowing. As per what you said/implied, when only battery is connected, this would supply the power for the system right? The battery voltage is around 4.2V and the input is disconnected. The PG doesn't and none of the STATx LEDs glow (I checked without the load and also loaded and checked). The battery supplies power to the load but the LEDs don't glow

Comment: @Newbie well, I can't say anything about your last observation because what I said is what datasheet says. Check if the load is supplied from the battery and try to discharge it further to see if LBO turns on.

Comment: What I did now - Disconnected the input voltage to the module. Connected the battery - 4.2V 300mAh battery. To check this LBO feature, I heavily loaded the OUT pins. I am drawing 1.5A of output current on the OUT pins. Now, the battery supplies the current and in sometime, the voltage dropped to 1.7V. At any point in time, I didn't see the STAT1 LED glowing as it went from 4.2V to 1.7V. Any idea?

Comment: @Newbie The datasheet (DC characteristics) indicates that the input voltage of the chip should not be lower than Vreg (by no more than 70mV, actually) which can be as high as 4.3V depending on the part. This contradicts the LBO function operation. In this case, you may not be able to get an LBO output while the input is way too low and the battery voltage is too low as well. Interesting. Let me have a look a bit deeper.

Comment: Sure, that's why I was confused on whether I will be able to achieve the LBO output at all

Comment: @Newbie see the update. If still doesn't work then there must be something wrong with the setup, board or chip.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is working as per the edit that you mentioned in your answer. Much appreciate your help!